# spring boot and thymeleaf - displaying All Elements

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Can you help me about showing all the elements in "book-data".html file?

My controller class is

```
@Autowired BooksService booksService
@GetMapping("/books")
private List<Books> getAllBooks() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    return booksService.getAllBooks();
}
```

and my service class is

```
@Autowired BooksRepository booksRepository;
public List<Books> getAllBooks() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    return (List<Books>) booksRepository.findAll();
}
```

my book repository interface is

```
public interface BooksRepository extends CrudRepository<Books, Integer>
{
}
```

and my "book-data".html file is

```
<table class="table">
<thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Book ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Book Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Book Author</th>
        <th scope="col">Book Price</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td th:text="${book.bookid}"></td>
        <td th:text="${book.bookname}"></td>
        <td th:text="${book.author}"></td>
        <td th:text="${book.price}"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

In HTML page, it doesn't show any book data. For service class, I saw another solution like below, but it didn't solve the problem.

```
@RequestMapping("/books")
private String listBooks(Model model){
  model.addAtrribute("books", booksService.getAllBooks());
  return "books";
}
```

in html:

```
<tbody>
    <tr th:each="book : ${books}">
          <td th:text="${book.bookid}"></td>
          <td th:text="${book.bookname}"></td>
          <td th:text="${book.author}"></td>
          <td th:text="${book.price}"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: Hello, in your html file you should had the html part that you put at the and of your question (with `th:each`)

Comment: I think you shuffle your code, between service and controller. I will post you something that should work. Your method is not correct, but you are not so far

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this is maybe a solution :

in your controller with adding `@Controller` in class statement :

```
@Autowired
BooksService booksService

@GetMapping("/books")
private String listBooks(Model model){
  model.addAtrribute("books", booksService.getAllBooks());
  return "views/book-data";
}
```

your service with adding `@Service` in class statement :

```
@Autowired
BooksRepository bookRepository

public List<Books> getAllBooks(){
  return this.booksRepository.findAll();
}
```

your repository with adding `@Repository` in class statement :
maybe you could had `@Query`

```
@Repository
public interface BooksRepository extends CrudRepository<Books, Long>
{
    public List<Books> findAll();
}
```

And your html :

```
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Book ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Book Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Book Author</th>
            <th scope="col">Book Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="book : ${books}">
          <td th:text="${book.bookid}"></td>
          <td th:text="${book.bookname}"></td>
          <td th:text="${book.author}"></td>
          <td th:text="${book.price}"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I already added the parts that you mentioned and nothing changed.

Comment: Update your code then. Because what is shown above is different than what I answered

Comment: In your controller first, your method should return String, the path to your html template

Comment: you have written service instead of controller at the end of your question too

Answer (score 0):

First, I created another html file that shows "all books". This file is named `allBooks.html`. Then, the service method below solved the problem, for your information.

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<html xmlns:th="https://thymeleaf.org">
<style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
<table class="table">
<thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Book ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Book Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Book Author</th>
        <th scope="col">Book Price</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr  th:each="book : ${books}">
        <td th:text="${book.bookid}"></td>
        <td th:text="${book.bookname}"></td>
        <td th:text="${book.author}"></td>
        <td th:text="${book.price}"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
@GetMapping("/books")
private ModelAndView getAllBooks() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("allBooks");
    mav.addObject("books", booksService.getAllBooks());
    return mav;
}
```